# Show Button or Image on top of screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on a Android Project in which I need to show a `Button or ImageView` on header of my activity(Screen). Below is my XML layout of my activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_margin="2px"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2px" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/BtnSlide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0px"
            android:padding="0px"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With the above layout, I can see my black `button image` just below the `Proximity` title. Is it possible to show my `button image` to left of `Proximity` instead of getting shown one line below Proximity?

[image]

**Or**

Is there any way, I can make the `image which is left to Proximity` title clickable? if I can do that, then I don't need to show Black Button image at the top.

That image is coming from AndroidManifest.xml file. I am not sure how to make that clickable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to make clickable logo icon in actionbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030204/android-how-to-make-clickable-logo-icon-in-actionbar)

Comment: @Sam may be it is not.. because he is not asking about actionbar, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the above layout, I can see my black button image just below the
>   Proximity title. Is it possible to show my button image to left of
>   Proximity instead of getting shown one line below Proximity?

Since Proximity is in titlebar you need to create your own custom titlebar to be able to place button to titlebar. Here is [`example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681081/android-adding-button-to-custom-title-bar) how to achieve it.

Also try to think an usage of [`ActionBar`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Button b=new Button(context);

    View v = findViewById (android.R.id.title);  // Getting the title bar view
     v.addView(b);    // setting Button
    v.setClickable(true);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You have clicked on Title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

How ever I'll suggest you to use `ActionBar`

Note: I haven't tried that. Let me know if it work for you