# Best way to customize action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to make the menu bar look like this: [image: this]:

I left a link since I can't post images yet. What's the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681081/android-adding-button-to-custom-title-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom action bar layout : custom_action_bar.xml

Put the title and the buttons in the layout.

Inflate the layout, attach clickListeners and set the view as the view of the ActionBar.

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);


    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText("...");

    v.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do your stuff 
        }
    });
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```